# Error no such element unable to locate element error when using selenium for python 3.6

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using the selenium python package to enable me to login into my router and change the password by simply running a script.
I have been able to use navigate till the page to enter the new password where I keep getting an error.

I have tried using both the values for and also accessed via the table elements.

```
#using chrome to access web
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://192.168.100.1/')

#find the username box and send value
driver.find_element_by_id('txt_Username').send_keys('root')

#find the password box and send value
driver.find_element_by_id('txt_Password').send_keys('@Idontlike5')

#click login button
driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()

#select advanced tab
driver.find_element_by_id('addconfig').click()

#select WLAN
driver.find_element_by_id('wlanconfig').click()

#input new password
wpa2 = driver.find_element_id('wlWpaPsk')
wpa2.clear()
wpa2.send_keys('21Savage')

#select 5g wlan
#wlan5g = driver.find_element_by_id('wlan5basic')

#click apply btn
apply = driver.find_element_by_id('btnApplySubmit')   
apply.click()
```

The id for the input for the new password should be correct but only returns an error.

I get this error at the end

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vans/Desktop/coding/y-fi??/net.py", line 37, in <module>
    wpa2 = driver.find_element_by_id('twlWpaPsk')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="wlWpaPsk"]"}
```

and a snippet of the source page

```
<td class="table_right">
            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" id="wlWpaPsk" name="wlWpaPsk" size="20" maxlength="64" class="amp_font" onchange="wpapskpassword=getValue('wlWpaPsk');getElById('twlWpaPsk').value=wpapskpassword;" title="The password is suggested to contain at least two of the following combinations: digits, uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and special characters.">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="twlWpaPsk" name="twlWpaPsk" size="20" maxlength="64" class="amp_font" style="display:none" onchange="wpapskpassword=getValue('twlWpaPsk');getElById('wlWpaPsk').value=wpapskpassword;" title="The password is suggested to contain at least two of the following combinations: digits, uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and special characters.">
            <input checked="" type="checkbox" id="hidewlWpaPsk" name="hidewlWpaPsk" value="on" onclick="ShowOrHideText('hidewlWpaPsk', 'wlWpaPsk', 'twlWpaPsk', wpapskpassword);">
            <script>document.write(cfg_wlancfgdetail_language['amp_wlanpassword_hide']);</script>Hide
            <font class="color_red">*</font><span class="gray">
            <script>
                document.write(cfg_wlancfgdetail_language['amp_wpa_psknote' + ('1' == kppUsedFlag ? '_63' : '')]);
            </script>(8-63 characters or 64 hexadecimal characters)</span>
<span class="gray" id="pskpasswordwarning" style="display:none;"></span></td>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What is the error you are getting? Please add the error to your question post!

Comment: wpa2 = driver.find_element_id('twlWpaPsk') might be different on each page load

Comment: I think while searching element if you update element id then your script will workwpa2 = driver.find_element_id('twlWpaPsk')